# query patients on dcm4che

Tags: java, hl7, dcm4che

Now I'm working with dcm4che.And I have the demand to query patients,stydies,instances,mwls and so on.For the reason that dcm4che web interfaces has implements that efficiently,I want to  check out how dcm4che accomplish that,but affter much efforts.I couldn't find out what codes the web called after I press the "search" button down.
I learned that the dcm4chee C-FIND can fill my demand,but I don't know how to do that?Can anyone give me some help?Some easy examples of hl7 or C-FIND can do this in java will be better.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the standard DICOM interfaces such as C-FIND.  The DICOM standard documents are of course the ultimate reference guide for this, and the dcm4che DICOM toolkit (which is used by the dcm4chee archive) is an implementation of DICOM in Java.  The toolkit has several examples of both client and server side services which will be helpful to you.  The dcm4che toolkit has several different versions: 1.4 which is used by dcm4chee, 2.x which is widely in use by many organizations, and 3.x which is still undergoing some development but is still worthy of being used.  See the [Sourceforge download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcm4che/files/) to get them.

If you are writing services which are going to be used inside of dcm4chee, then I would use dcm4che14 because it is already included and highly integrated in dcm4chee.  If your service will run outside of dcm4chee, then I would go with either dcm4che2 or dcm4che3 (if you want to be on the cutting edge).  When you decide which toolkit you want to use and download it, you should get both the source and binary distributions.  The binary will be used as a library to your application, and also have the compiled example utilities for you to play around with .  The source distribution will have the source code of the examples so that you can see how to write your own application.

You may also want to join the [dcm4che google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dcm4che) in order to ask questions of other users and developers.